# How can I search the parameter of a specific object on Salesforce with rest api?

Tags: rest-api, search

I am currently working on the project that I am to connect the application of my company and salesforce.

> Now, I want to search for the specific parameter of the object with
> GET request but I don't know how.

EDITED******

The fact is that I want to search in CarInformation__c if there are any object that has ManagementNo__c that is "123"

I have been trying something like these.

```
https://instance.my.salesforce.com//services/data/v52.0/queryAll/?q=SELECT+Name+from+CarInformation__c+Where+ManagementNo__c+%7B123%7D
```

and the error says

```
[{"message"=>"\nCarInformation__c Where ManagementNo__c {113}\n                                       ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:57\nunexpected token: '{'", "errorCode"=>"MALFORMED_QUERY"}]%
```

I have also tried this.

```
https://instance.my.salesforce.com//services/data/v52.0/search/?q=FIND+%7B113%7D")
```

but it returns every sobject that have 123 in any field. I want it to be just an object that have 123 from ManagementNo__c

I guess that I might have to use "query" or "Parameterized Search" and I tried them but I don't know how to set the specific parameter like "123"

If you have any idea , I will really appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try `SELECT+Name+from+CarInformation__c+Where+fieldname=123` ?

Comment: `I can get the response but I need to get the parameter of the object that has "123" in the CarInformation__c object.`
Based on the statement above, are you seeking to get the field API name which contains the value 123 across the object fields?

Comment: @glls thank you for your comment. I tried the one you told me but the response says `[{"message"=>"\nSELECT Name from CarInformation__c Where fieldname=123\n                 ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:18\nsObject type 'CarInformation__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.", "errorCode"=>"INVALID_TYPE"}]%   `

Comment: i hope you replaced fieldname with the appropriate field name of the custom object

Comment: @SunilKumar thank you for you comment. what I want to do is to find out if there are any objects that have "123" in the field of CarInformation__c. in order for that I wanted to search it.

Comment: @glls I am sorry I think I misunderstood and updated my question . would you please  check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write proper SOQL to find records with a specific value in a specific field. That should look like:

```
SELECT Name FROM CarInformation__c WHERE ManagementNo__c = '123'
```

Of course, you need to encode the special characters, so the final URL will look like:

```
/services/data/v52.0/query?q=SELECT+Name+FROM CarInformation__c+WHERE+ManagementNo__c+%3D+%27123%27
```

You only use queryAll if you want to also include deleted records (those in the recycle bin). You only use the FIND syntax if you want to find a value in all search-indexed fields.

For specific details on how to write a SOQL query, check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm).

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. and I am sorry that I asked a lot. I mean it.
your answer perfectly worked. thank you so much.
I didn't even know about encoding the url. I learned a lot