# How can I find out if there are any object that has specific value?

Tags: rest-api, api, search, ruby

I am using rest api and trying to find out if there is a certain object that have certain value I gave.

to be precise, I want to know if there is any object that has ManagementNo__c which has 113 in the field.

I have been trying something like these.

```
https://instance.my.salesforce.com//services/data/v52.0/queryAll/?q=SELECT+Name+from+CarInformation__c+Where+ManagementNo__c+%7B113%7D
```

and the error says

```
[{"message"=>"\nCarInformation__c Where ManagementNo__c {113}\n                                       ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:57\nunexpected token: '{'", "errorCode"=>"MALFORMED_QUERY"}]%
```

I have also tried this.

```
https://instance.my.salesforce.com//services/data/v52.0/search/?q=FIND+%7B113%7D")
```

but it returns all sobject that have 123 in any field while I want it to be just an object that have 123 from ManagementNo__c

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions. Sometimes all you need is to wait a bit (I literally just answered your [older question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/349569/2984) a moment ago).

Comment: @sfdcfox
thank you so much and I am sorry for that. you helped me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first request is almost correct, but fields value should not be enclosed in `{113}`, but in quotes`'113'`. Here is what your `q` param should look like:

```
SELECT Name FROM CarInformation__c WHERE ManagementNo__c = '113'
```